# ArcGIS10.5.1 Data Merge error: 000732

Tags: arcpy, merge, error-000732

I am trying to run a python script to merge some files in a folder test, called test1.shp, test2.shp, test3.shp. 
The code is this:

```py
import os
import arcpy    
workspace = "C:/mypath/test/"       
prefixed = [filename for filename in os.listdir(workspace) if filename.startswith("test")]   
total = "C:/mypath/test/Merged.shp"    
arcpy.Merge_management(prefixed, total)
```

and I keep having the same error:

```
ERROR 000732:  Dataset test1.cpg;test1.dbf;test1.prj;test1.sbn;test1.sbx;test1.shp;test1.shp.xml;test1.shx;test2.cpg;test2.dbf;test2.prj;test2.sbn;test2.sbx;test2.shp;test2.shp.xml;test2.shx;test3.cpg;test3.dbf;test3.prj;test3.sbn;test3.sbx;test3.shp;test3.shp.xml;test3.shx does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (Merge).
```

I tried to force to merge only .shp files adding 'and filename.endswith(".shp"), and I have the same error, only with only .shp files.

I tried with a list in which each file has the entire path:

```py
l =[]
for i in prefixed:
     l.append ('"'+workspace +i+'"')    
total = "C:/mypath/test/Merged.shp"    
arcpy.Merge_management(l, total)
```

I tried to write my path using ' or using '//' instead, but I always have the same error message.

If I try a simple:

```
total = "C:/mypath/test/Merged.shp"    
arcpy.Merge_management(["C:/mypath/test/test1.shp", "C:/mypath/test/test2.shp", "C:/mypath/test/test3.shp"], total)
```

everything works fine.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ListFeatureClasses](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) with a wildcard:

> Lists the feature classes in the workspace, limited by name, feature
>   type, and optional feature dataset

You dont need to worry about other files since only feature classes will be listed.

```
import arcpy

folder = r'C:\shapefile_folder'
arcpy.env.workspace = folder
total = r'C:\mypath\test\Merged.shp'

shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(wild_card='*test*')
arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=shapefiles, output=total)
```